# Civicrm SagePay takes the primary address as billing address

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, civicrm-home

I just came across this error in Civicrm. We have sage pay payment intergration with our site.

The issue is that even when someone enters the billing address civicrm passes primary address to sagepay . This is a general issue and is happening with all the module ie - civiEven, Contribution,

My assumption is an error in the payment processor that passes the values to sage pay

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

ex : 
[image: Got a profile with billing addresses]
[image: Sage Pay Payment page]

Comment: Yes, Sagepay picks primary address as billing address you can change the code to look for billing address by making the changes in sagepay.php file

Answer (score 1):

apparently its something to do with the circle interactive sagepay payment plugin

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question.  Could you provide a bit more detail so that this is more helpful to other people who have the same problem.